# Load XML file to HTML(aspx) page and to set text label

Tags: asp.net, xml

i'm just starting to program in ASP.Net VB and I need help! I have a few HTML(aspx) pages and for each page his XML file. When I visit any of these pages I want to read his XML file and set texts for labels. How i can do that??? For examle:

**xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<page>
        <title>Page Number One:</title>
        <chapter1>Main Chapter:</chapter1>
        <chapter2>Second Chapter:</chapter2>

         ...

</page>
```

**html page:**

```
...
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="<%= title %>">"></asp:Label>

        <asp:Label ID="lblFName" runat="server" Text="<%= chapter1 %>"></asp:Label>

        <asp:Label ID="lblLName" runat="server" Text="<%= chapter2 %>"></asp:Label>

    </form>

 ...
```

something like that or better way to do that??? Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [XDocument to load/parse the file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument), then XPath to get the value of the nodes you need.

In order to use the binding expressions like you posted, you'd need to use a data bound control like a repeater and [an XMLDataSource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10898/Introduction-to-XMLDataSource-control-in-ASP-NET-2).